# Python 3: CSV file is filled with empty rows when opened with Excel on Windows

Tags: python, windows, excel, csv, python-3.4

I am writing a code in Python 3.4, which gives me several CSV-files as output. When I open those files with Excel 2010 on Windows 8.1 (64bit, x64 processor), there is an empty row after every row with actual content. Does anyone has a solution for that? In several posts I could read, that I should use 'wb' instead of 'w', but this refers to Python 2.7. My code in Python 3.4 looks as follows:

```
with open('csv_file.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf8') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    w.writerow(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

The problem does not go away if I set "newline=''" instead of "newline='\n'".

The interesting thing is, that I have not any problems to open it in Excel 2016 on OS X 10.11. There are no additional blank rows after content rows.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Look at the actual *.csv-file; open it in a text editor. Are there too many newlines in there? If not, the problem is with Excel. If yes, it's the way you write the code. In your example you write only one line; how do you write multiple lines?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html#csv.writer -> https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html#id3

Comment: If I open it in the text editor it looks completely fine (no empty lines). So the problem is with Excel?

Comment: How do you open the `CSV` file with excel? What happens if you try it using Excel's text import wizard? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857

Comment: I can open it over the import wizard (no blank lines with the correct parameters), but it is just not too convenient, since I have to open 500+ files...

Comment: So what are the "correct parameters"? And btw. I don't see the big difference between double clicking 500 files or using the wizard 500 times. Maybe seconds each time. And btw. using `newline=''` will be absolutely necessary.

Comment: "correct parameters" means set the delimiters to "comma".

Comment: have you tried with newline='\r\n'?

Comment: Yes I have... that even gives me 2 lines.

Comment: You need to provide an example which actually demonstrates the problem. As it is, your code would produce only one row anyway, so blank rows would not be an issue. That said, I tried simply copying your `writerow` line to produce more rows, and it worked normally, with no intervening blank rows. This is regardless of whether I set the `newline` parameter to `'\n'` or the empty string.